# Truffle Installation failure -ECONNREFUSED

Tags: truffle

I have read numerous posting on this. I don't see an answer. I'm trying to install this on my Ubuntu via the command sudo npm install -g truffle

My Ubuntu is installed on Windows. It asks if there is some proxy.  I tried the commands

npm set proxy null
npm set https-proxy null

How does one set the ERR proxy config correctly? Why isn't all this stuff done automatically?

> npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
> npm ERR! syscall connect
> npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
> npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/truffle failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 2606:4700::6810:1a22:443
> npm ERR!     at ClientRequest. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
> npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
> npm ERR!     at _destroy (node:_http_client:882:13)
> npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:902:5)
> npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
> npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/truffle failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 2606:4700::6810:1a22:443
> npm ERR!     at ClientRequest. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
> npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
> npm ERR!     at _destroy (node:_http_client:882:13)
> npm ERR!     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:902:5)
> npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
> npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
> npm ERR!   address: '2606:4700::6810:1a22',
> npm ERR!   port: 443,
> npm ERR!   type: 'system',
> npm ERR!   requiredBy: '.'
> npm ERR! }
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: does your vm have proper internet setup? can you ping registry.npmjs.org?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda of silly. I turned off my VPN and it worked.